# Single store on multiple domains - Opencart

Tags: opencart, multilingual, multiple-domains

I would like to know how to setup a store to run on multiple domains.

Posible Scenario :

> The main store is "**store.de**" and i would like to make it to use
>   diffrent domains such as "**store.com** ; **store.fr** ..etc" but the
>   store is the same as theme , products , users , etc .
>
> The only thing I would like to change is when someone gets an a
>   language specific domain such as "**.fr** ; **.de** " to be able  to
>   set automatic the store language to that specific zone , because
>   opencart only detects the browser language ( I'm not really sure about
>   that )

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your main store is store.com and you have already pointed your main store to all other domains. Now you can make a small vqmod or ocmod (OC v.2) which can be appended in catalog/controller/common/header.php For example:

Append these:

```
$tld = substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],strrpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],'.')+1);

if ( !isset($this->session->data['lang_detect']) && $tld! = 'com') {
    $this->session->data['language'] = $tld;
    $this->session->data['lang_detect'] = true; 
}
```

Before:

```
$this->data['base'] = $server;
```

Comment: At the moment the main store is store.de and on it i builded the store with all the products and languages.. So, how do i create extra domains buy use the same store "store.de" files and database?

Comment: You can point other domains to the store.de server. Please contact your server guy for managing domain DNS.  In your main store, please keep all languages file e.g. english, spanish etc that your required

Comment: And for each domain i add the $tld! = 'com'. Example for. Fr i change the tld to 'fr'. But how whould this data detect that the language for .fr will be french or any othet domain like .de german?

Comment: I am assuming your domain tld is same as your lang code. For example, for fr, your language code will be fr. OC detect language based on the session var $this->session->data['language'] on site. So you can simply set $this->session->data['language'] depending on domain tld